# Line Level Scala Coverage Reports w/ Emma / Ant

Tags: scala, code-coverage, emma, scalac

Are there any tricks that I need to use to get Line Level coverage reports working w/ Scala code using Emma?  I can get it working w/ Java code fine, but for some reason the debug info is not getting into the class files when I use scalac.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it would be practical using Emma for Scala code coverage:
As mentioned in "[Partial EMMA code coverage in Scala Case Class for IntelliJ IDEA 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084309/partial-emma-code-coverage-in-scala-case-class-for-intellij-idea-10-5)", as an example of the issue you would face is most of the method generated in the bytecode would be reported at the same line number as the class definition.

The answer "[Code Coverage Tools for Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953998/code-coverage-tools-for-scala)" mentions **[scct](http://mtkopone.github.com/scct/)** as the Code Coverage tool of choice for Scala. (source code [on gitHub](https://github.com/mtkopone/scct)).

[image: scct]

Considering it ("theoretically") supports now  scala 2.9.+, you could use it first, and see if it works better.